# Access Form passing PK to some underlying tables, but not others

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a query based off of 8 tables that hold Part data for different departments. I bring all of these together for a form used to create new Parts. When I use this form to create new parts, it adds the PK into some of those tables, but not others.

Below is a screenshot of my testing, and the Query underlying the form
[image: Testing Failure]

[image: Query Design View]

It is always leaving them out of RIPMDF, WrapFoil, as well as the Notes portion.

These  **'Access_ID'** fields are combo-boxes with 2 columns. The first is the actual autogenerated Access_ID, and displaying is the Part Number associated with it. I wouldn't be surprised if this is the source of my issue - I have read that using these can be confusing to work with, especially for those without formal training.

I have been attempting a workaround using VBA/SQL to insert the PK to the other tables, but I would like to solve it the proper way, assuming there is one, instead of a workaround.

Comment: in the design view of the affected tables with those combo boxes, look at the properties of the combo boxes themselves. It might be obvious if a property setting is the issue youre facing.

Answer (score 0):

So, like I said in my comments, you need to look at the properites of your combo boxes in the table design view of the affected tables. This would have been a comment but I feel like visual aides are needed :)

See how I made a point to illustrate Bound Column, ColumnCount, and List Width? Bound Column is "the actual value of the selection despite the display value", ColumnCount is "number of display columns for drop down" and ListWidth is a way to set the width value of your columns using this logic "1;2;0;" (if you have three columns, with the last one being 0 which translates anecdotally to "not visible").

There is a chance it is something else, but at least you can start here to see if this helps you find your answer.

[image]

Comment: This was the first area I looked at, all of my combo's have the same properties. Those being: Row Source: `SELECT [Tbl_MasterPartsList].[Access_ID], [Tbl_MasterPartsList].[Part_Number] FROM Tbl_MasterPartsList` Bound Column: `1` Column Count: `2` Column Width: `0";1"` List Width: `1"`

Comment: I think maybe changing column width 0 to >0 might show the hidden primary key?

Comment: It's not a problem of the PK's visibility. With the workaround mentioned above I am attempting to Insert a blank record (besides PK obviously) into the Tables that Access isn't Inserting to. My main question here was - does anyone know _why_ Access is doing this for some Tables but not others? The properties between all of these `Access_ID` fields are the same across the board. I have almost got the workaround functional, but if this is a design/other problem I'd like to fix the origin of it rather than make a 'fix' that may cause issues further down the line, or just plain breakdown.